# How to stop friend requests from friends of friends

Tags: facebook

How can I stop friend requests from "friends of friends" when I don't have a clue who those people are? I have a Facebook account to keep up with people I know personally who have moved away, but I don't know any of the people in their new area(s) and don't want those requests.

Comment: Just ignore those requests, that's what everyone does ;)

Answer (score 4):

You can’t. The only two options for receiving friend requests are *Everybody* and *Friends of Friends*.

Comment: Which makes sense. Otherwise people wouldn't be able to make friend requests, which is what the site is all about. You can, of course, limit who can find you by only allowing Friends to find you with an email or phone number search.